# Right align p:inputNumber in a p:dataTable

Tags: css, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I've coded a PrimeFaces (JSF / Java) `p:dataTable` that uses `p:inputNumber` for each cell. Everything works, but the table looks ragged due to the left-alignment of `p:inputNumber`'s content. All of the formatting I've tried formats the control itself, not its content.

Is there any way to right-align the content of a `p:inputNumber`?

Comment: you are using custom template or cell editing?

Answer (score 7):

If someone in 2020 or later is visiting this page:

For PrimeNG 10 the Angular ngStyle Syntax is needed for input style. Just do the following:

```
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="0.00" [inputStyle]="{'text-align': 'right'}"></p-inputNumber>
```

**Update 2023:**

The above is still a possibility. But when using primeflex I like this solution better, using the already available 'text-right'-class:

```
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="0.00" inputStyleClass="text-right"></p-inputNumber>
```

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces, not about PrimeNG.

Answer (score 5):

For `inputNumber` there are attributes `inputStyle` and `inputStyleClass`.

I managed to get my number input's right aligned like this:

```html
<p:inputNumber value="0.00" inputStyle="text-align: right" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like

```
span.ui-inputnumber > input[type=text] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

That should catch all p:inputNumber's everywhere.

Comment: You could also use this selector: `.ui-inputnumber .ui-inputtext`. It will come down to the same.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 with angular 11 and primeng v11.3.2 [@J-Eibe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64372171/8949981) is still valid if you just want to style a single `p-inputNumber`, but if you want some more generic, place the following code in your style.css

```
.p-inputnumber-input{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: nice! found my own answer 1,5 years later and got an even nicer solution :)

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces, not about PrimeNG.

Comment: Apart from that, it's basically https://stackoverflow.com/a/44106494/880619 but then for a different component library (which the question is not about).